# How to convert list to map with multiple keys and value as list using java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of `Users(id,ssn,name)` and need to convert as Map of list of ssns and list of ids. Could you help with this?

```
List.of(new User(1, "ssn1", "user1"), new User(2, "ssn2", "user2"), new User(3, "ssn3", "user3"))
```

---

```
Map with 2 keys("SSNs","IDs") and list as value
"SSNs" -  List("ssn1","ssn2","ssn3")
"IDs" -  List(1,2,3)
```

#### Code

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<User> users = List.of(new User(1, "ssn1", "user1"), new User(2, "ssn2", "user2"),
                new User(3, "ssn3", "user3"));

        Map<String, List<Object>> userMap = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getSsn));
    
    }

}

class User {
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getSsn() {
        return ssn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    int id;
    String ssn;
    String name;

    public User(int id, String ssn, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.ssn = ssn;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Update:** Updated `List<User>` to `List<Object>`.

Comment: so you want a Map of `<String, List<Object>>` or `<String, List<?>>` that maps the name of a field to a list of existing values of that field?

Comment: I need map with 2 keys, one with value of list of string another with value of list of ints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s not necessarily an improvement over [a loop solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472852/2711488) but you can solve the task using the Stream API like this:

```java
Map<String, List<Object>> result = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.mapping(User::getId, Collectors.toList()),
        Collectors.mapping(User::getSsn, Collectors.toList()),
        (id, ssn) -> Map.of("IDs", id, "SSNs", ssn)));
```

Above example works with Eclipse. It seems, javac has problems with the type inference. The following works on both:

```java
Map<String, List<Object>> result = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.mapping(User::getId, Collectors.<Object>toList()),
        Collectors.mapping(User::getSsn, Collectors.<Object>toList()),
        (id, ssn) -> Map.of("IDs", id, "SSNs", ssn)));
```

Alternatively

```java
Map<String, List<?>> result = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.mapping(User::getId, Collectors.toList()),
        Collectors.mapping(User::getSsn, Collectors.toList()),
        (id, ssn) -> Map.of("IDs", id, "SSNs", ssn)));
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple for loop can solve your problem, instead of using stream, I would suggest using this simple readable solution:

```
Map<String, List<Object>> userMap = new HashMap<>();
userMap.put("SSNs", new ArrayList<>());
userMap.put("IDs", new ArrayList<>());
for (User user: users) {
    userMap.get("IDs").add(user.getId());
    userMap.get("SSNs").add(user.getSsn());
}
```

#### Result

```
{IDs=[1, 2, 3], SSNs=[ssn1, ssn2, ssn3]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was expecting if something can be done using java streams not regular one.

Comment: This solution is magnitudes better in terms of readability.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a `Map` that has a known constant number of entries (2), and a known constant set of keys ("SSNs" and "IDs"). That sounds as if your code would be much simpler if you just held the values in two separate variables, instead of trying to cram them into a two-entry Map. However, if you really want that, you have to create your lists as `List<Object>` instead of being the more natural `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`.

```
    List<Object> ids = users.stream().map(user -> (Object) user.getId()).toList();
    List<Object> ssns = users.stream().map(user -> (Object) user.getSsn()).toList();
    Map<String, List<Object>> userMap = Map.of("IDs", ids, "SSNs", ssns);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative but not as elegant as [Holgers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77473534/1552534). At a minimum, the idea can be applied to similar requirements. For example, since teeing is limited to two streams (although I believe this limitation could be overcome), you could also put `consumer.accept(Map.entry("Names", user.getName()));` as a third entry to be processed with no additional changes required.

- First, stream the user instances.
- Then, using [mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) (introduced in Java 16) in combinaton with `Map.entry`, create an entry that contains the `Map key` and the associated `value` to put in a list. Then using `consumer.accept`, place each entry on the stream.
- Then group the elements by the entry key and map the entry values to a list.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> result = users.stream()
   .<Entry<String, Object>>mapMulti((user, consumer) -> {
         consumer.accept(Map.entry("SSNs", user.getSsn()));
         consumer.accept(Map.entry("IDs", user.getId())); 
    }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey,
        Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
SSNs=[ssn1, ssn2, ssn3]
IDs=[1, 2, 3]
```

Note the type witnessing `<Entry<String, Object>>` for the `mapMulti` method.  In many cases, it is required as the compiler cannot determine the resulting type to be placed on the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely consider @Youcef's solution. Trying to do what you wanted really seems to make a mess of things. See below:

```
public class tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Function<User, Object>> fields = new HashMap<>();
        fields.put("SSNs", User::getSsn);
        fields.put("Ids", User::getId);
        List<User> users = List.of(new User(1, "ssn1", "user1"), new User(2, "ssn2", "user2"),
                new User(3, "ssn3", "user3"));
        Map<String, List<Object>> map = fields.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> users.stream().map(u -> e.getValue().apply(u)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(map);
//        Map<String, List<User>> userMap = users.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getSsn));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{SSNs=[ssn1, ssn2, ssn3], Ids=[1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see what benefit you are getting from creating a `Map` here. If you need to pass in both lists to a function you'd be better off creating an object that holds your 2 lists.

```
class UsersList {

    //... getters

    List<Integer> ids;
    List<String> ssns;

    public UsersList(List<User> users) {
        this.ids = new ArrayList<>();
        this.ssns = new ArrayList<>();
        users.forEach((u) -> {
            ids.add(u.getId());
            ssns.add(u.getSsn());
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can pass in your list to the constructor and you can access both lists like this:

```
   UsersList usersList = new UsersList(users);

   System.out.println("ids: " + usersList.ids);
   System.out.println("ssns: " + usersList.ssns);
```

Edit: Updated the constructor to use 1 stream instead.

Comment: I wanted to know with a single stream call how to do it. I know, using multiple stream calls it will work.

Comment: @sunleo That's a good point. I have updated the constructor to use 1 stream instead.